# Taking sum From a table and trying to update that rows in another

Tags: sql

here is everything i tried yet !

```
UPDATE DailyBooking
SET RecievedAmount =
(
    SELECT DailyBooking.ID, 
        (SELECT  SUM(RecipientDetails.Amount) FROM RecipientDetails
         WHERE RecipientDetails.DBID = DailyBooking.ID)
    FROM DailyBooking
    INNER JOIN RecipientDetails
        ON RecipientDetails.DBID = DailyBooking.ID 
 )
```

this query is throwing error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

and when i try that with where clause like :

```
 UPDATE DailyBooking SET RecievedAmount=(
    SELECT DailyBooking.ID, 
    (SELECT  SUM(RecipientDetails.Amount) FROM RecipientDetails
    WHERE RecipientDetails.DBID = DailyBooking.ID) FROM DailyBooking INNER JOIN RecipientDetails ON 
    RecipientDetails.DBID =DailyBooking.ID 
     ) where DailyBooking.ID = RecipientDetails.DBID
```

it is throwing error like :

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The multi-part identifier
>   "RecipientDetails.DBID" could not be bound.

Tables !
1 Table Providing Sum :
[RecipientDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XC2Q.png)

2. Table having RecievedAmount Column:

[DailyBooking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TaLx.png)

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: View..? wanna see the tables view..?

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: SQL @scaisEdge .

Comment: @scaisEdge The error message strongly looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   .. thanks  .. I did not notice it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have the inner SQL return more than 1 value, since it's result is what the `SET` recieves.

Try this (will not work in all DBs, but you didn't specify which one you use):

```
UPDATE DailyBooking d
SET d.RecievedAmount =
(
   SELECT  SUM(RecipientDetails.Amount) FROM RecipientDetails            
   WHERE RecipientDetails.DBID = d.ID
)
```

Comment: You Just Saved my day ! 
and now  i m shamed that how freaky way i was trying

Comment: You're welcome, if this answer helped you mark it as correct and upvote.

Comment: Marked as correct but really sorry that i cant upvote any answer

Comment: this was the simplest and the best one @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: yeah i know actually i can say it was the best one for all the time @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move your aggregation query into a CTE and then join update with it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DBID, SUM(Amount) AS RecievedAmount
    FROM RecipientDetails
    GROUP BY DBID
)
UPDATE db
SET RecievedAmount = t.RecievedAmount
FROM DailyBooking db
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON db.ID = t.DBID;
```

This should perform better than updating via a correlated subquery to compute the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
UPDATE DailyBooking
SET RecievedAmount =
 (SELECT  SUM(RecipientDetails.Amount) FROM RecipientDetails
     WHERE RecipientDetails.DBID = DailyBooking.ID)
FROM DailyBooking
INNER JOIN RecipientDetails
    ON RecipientDetails.DBID = DailyBooking.ID
```

Comment: I am simply stating that the answer you accepted is not optimal.